# How to quickly identify who carries which weapon?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have an under-armed vault. That is, I only have 3 or 4 weapons in a vault with almost 30 dwellers. When there's an invasion, I often have to quickly scramble a defense squad but I cannot tell who's got the big guns.

**How can I quickly tell who's got which weapon?**

Does the game provide an interface that let's you find that out quickly? If not, what would be a useful way for me to keep track of who's carrying which gun?

Comment: The best way to handle this is to take all the guns away when they're not in use, and just hand them out when they're needed.

Comment: I recommend you send out a couple of poorly equipped dwellers and scramble up a few bad guns. Also, try to keep completing missions to keep them flowing, and always try to find lunchbox missions. Getting a decent weapon from an early lunchbox will make a huge difference to your game.

Comment: The best way to handle this is to get more guns. Everybody should be armed all the time, with the people near the entrance having *better* guns. I have learned this the hard way. Don't expand your population if you don't have a gun for the new person.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the update awhile ago, this has actually become quite simple. When selecting a weapon for a dweller, the default list has the leftmost column labeled "Inventory", and shows all unequipped weapons. If you tap that, it will change to "Equipped", showing all weapons currently equipped along with who carries them. Tapping again gets you "All", which contains all equipped and unequipped weapons.

Answer (score 10):

Outdated, now you can see that quickly when assigning a weapon to a Dweller. See [other answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/282980/196081).

<sub>I still like my redhead squad, though.</sub>

---

<s>**You cannot.**</s>

The only gun carriers you can quickly identify are those guarding the gate, since they have their weapons drawn.

<s>The game gives you no quick way to identify all weapon carriers, so you will have to be organized.</s>

You could, for example :

- Give weapons only when needed, then take them back (as suggested in on of the comments)
- Have your "defense squad" stationed in one particular area of your vault
- Give the weapon only to certain people : people with military suits (so RP !), women with red hair…